# Camera of Turtlebot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

which type of kinect camera is used with turtlebot ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45794/camera-of-turtlebot/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The original Kinect not Kinect For Windows.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0